# Pygame: window not responding

Tags: python, pygame

I'm an ameatur coder and I have recently started with pygame and I have been coding some examples and I have just come to one that won't load properly when executed. I am pretty sure I have written it correctly but I can't figure out why it won't run.
I am running python 3.6 and Pygame 1.9.3.*

*I know the pygame version is 1.9 of sorts but I don't know the last digit.

Here's the code:

```
# This just imports all the Pygame modules
import pygame

# This MUST BE the first thing you put into a program!
pygame.init()
# This tells pygame to open a windo 640 pixels by 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

# This is called a while loop
# This is the simplest form of an event loop
# This line procceses the window: Such as telling it to close when the user     hits the Escape Key
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
# Y = DOWN
class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        image = pygame.image.load('player.png')

        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key ==     pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            screen.blit(image, (320, 240))
            pygame.display.flip()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
        Game().main(screen)
```

Comment: I may have added unneeded code by accident.

Comment: You used copy&paste programming without knowing what the code does. Take a step back and try to understand the code. Start with the first `while` loop.

Comment: Sorry I coded all of this from a video for a class but they broke everything up so I thought everything was supposed to be all in one file.

Comment: Because I understand what it says. I just don't know why it won't run.

Comment: I just now ran this but it still won't display what I want it to display:

Comment: import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

Comment: class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):     
        image = pygame.image.load('player.png')

        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            screen.blit(image, (320, 240))
            pygame.display.flip()

Comment: Is the code outdated?

Comment: I think it is just because a lot of the time pygame doesn't want to run it.

Comment: Your first `while` loop runs without doing anything.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code so it will now run. The main issue that I detect is that you don't understand exactly what the code is doing when it is ran.

**Issues fixed:**

- Removed a pointless while loop and pygame initializations that were done below in the beginning of the program's execution anyway.
- Unindented the `if __name__ == "__main__":` branch. This branch is **never part of a class**. In a class you have methods and variables. **That is it**.

Other than those issues the code is alright but make sure you understand what it does before moving on.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

**Revised code example:**

```
# This just imports all the Pygame modules
import pygame

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        image = pygame.image.load('player.png')

        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            screen.blit(image, (320, 240))
            pygame.display.flip()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    Game().main(screen)
```